# When I am updating a row, all rows in gridview is getting updated

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am using RowUpdating event in Gridview. When I am updating a row, all rows in gridview is getting updated. My code is

```
Con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dbo.PersionalDetails set Name='" + txtName.Text + "',Location='" + txtLocation.Text + "' where id=id", Con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Con.Close();
Label lblresult = new Label();
lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
lblresult.Text = txtName.Text + " Details Updated successfully";
GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
BindGrid();
```

Please help!!

Comment: Id always equals id.. first off remove the sql injection `'';DROP TABLE xxx; --`.... And change your where 'id=id' to parameters

Answer (score 4):

That's because `where id = id` is `true` for all rows. It is like `where 1 = 1` and it is equal to `where TRUE`. That's why your all rows updated.

From [`=` (Equals) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx)

```
expression = expression
```

> Return Types
>
> Boolean

Since `id`'s are column names, they are valid [expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx).

I strongly feels like you want to add this `id` as a parameter but you didn't even mentioned any parameter in your code, so..

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandText = "update dbo.PersionalDetails set Name = @name, Location = @location where id = @id";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtLocation.Text );
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", YourIdValue);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

## But more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Since we didn't know your column types, I used `AddWithValue` in my example but don't use this method. Use [`.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add.aspx) as a best practice.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: but if he want to update the particular row then he has to pass the value for id...isnt it?

Comment: @rushankshah That's right. When he pass the `id` as a value, it matches only row's that have this value in `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

change your where clause with the following:

```
where id='"+id+"'
```

and pass the value for id

Its done!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your where clause and correct it ,it is always TRUE

One more thing DO read about the SQL INJECTION, and change your coding style.(This code will not survive on internet!)